# Why is SQL Loader/External Table not working with null value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

The code below was working all along but since we've upgrade from 12c to 19c, it's stopped. It's going wrong in the other_name and birth_date part. Other_name is primarily blank in the csv so null should be uploaded. When it's blank now, it's causing birth_date to go wrong (getting
error processing column BIRTH_DATE in row 2 for datafile
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected)

If i amend the file manually myself to add something into other_name, it works then though.

Anyone seen an issue like this before, and know how to fix?

```
    ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = dbo;

--
-- Product Category File 
--

DROP TABLE mis_product_category_ext;

CREATE TABLE mis_product_category_ext
                         (
                           PACKAGE_LABEL     varchar2(4),
                           PACKAGE_DESCR     varchar2(64),
                           PACKAGE_CAT       varchar2(10)
                        )
           ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
           ( 
             TYPE ORACLE_LOADER 
             DEFAULT DIRECTORY SEPA_FILES
             ACCESS PARAMETERS 
             ( 
               records delimited by newline 
               badfile SEPA_FILES:'mis_product_category_ext.bad'
               logfile SEPA_FILES:'mis_product_category_ext.log'
               skip 1
               fields terminated by ','
               missing field values are null 
               ( 
                package_label,package_descr,package_cat
               )
             ) 
             LOCATION ('product_category.csv') 
           ) 
           REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED; 
           
declare
--
   v_insurer varchar2(10);
--
begin

--
-- Incoming data files from insurers
--

   for i in 1..3 loop
   --
      case i
         when 1 then v_insurer := 'aviva';
         when 2 then v_insurer := 'glohealth';
         when 3 then v_insurer := 'vhi';
      end case;
   --
      for i in (select table_name from all_tables where lower(table_name) = 'mis_mem_verify_ext_'||v_insurer||'') loop
         execute immediate 'DROP TABLE mis_mem_verify_ext_'||v_insurer||'';
      end loop;
   --
      execute immediate
      'CREATE TABLE mis_mem_verify_ext_'||v_insurer||'
                         (
                           REQ_INSURERS_PRIMARY_KEY         varchar2(100),
                           UNIQUE_REFERENCE_ID_1            varchar2(100),
                           NAME_OF_LAST_INSURER             varchar2(10),
                           FIRSTNAME                        varchar2(60),
                           SURNAME                          varchar2(60),
                           OTHER_NAME                       varchar2(60),
                           BIRTH_DATE                       date,
                           FIRST_LINE_OF_ADDRESS            varchar2(60),
                           COUNTY                           varchar2(30),
                           UNIQUE_REFERENCE_ID_2            varchar2(15),
                           PRODUCT_TYPE                     varchar2(15),
                           PLAN_NAME                        varchar2(100),
                           START_DATE_OF_POLICY             date,
                           END_DATE_OF_POLICY               date,
                           MEM_MATCH                        varchar2(1),
                           CREDITED_PERIOD                  number(4),
                           UNEMPLOYMENT_PERIOD              number(4),
                           LCR_LOADING                      number,
                           LOADING_OVERRIDDEN               varchar2(1)
                        )
           ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
           ( 
             TYPE ORACLE_LOADER 
             DEFAULT DIRECTORY SEPA_FILES
             ACCESS PARAMETERS 
             ( 
               records delimited by newline 
               badfile SEPA_FILES:''mem_verify_'||v_insurer||'_incoming.bad''
               logfile SEPA_FILES:''mem_verify_'||v_insurer||'_incoming.log''
               skip 1
               fields terminated by 0X''09''
               LRTRIM
               missing field values are null 
               ( req_insurers_primary_key,unique_reference_id_1,name_of_last_insurer,firstname,
                 surname,other_name,birth_date char date_format date mask "yyyy-mm-dd",first_line_of_address,
                 county,unique_reference_id_2,product_type,plan_name,start_date_of_policy char date_format date mask "yyyy-mm-dd",
                 end_date_of_policy char date_format date mask "yyyy-mm-dd",mem_match,credited_period,unemployment_period,
                 lcr_loading,loading_overridden
               )
             ) 
             LOCATION (''lcr_mem_verification_'||v_insurer||'_incoming.csv'') 
           ) 
           PARALLEL 
           REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED'; 
   --
   end loop;
--
end;
/

spool off;

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  line OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ‘"’ from the control file.

SQL*Loader treats blank/tab as white space. As soon as it finds white space, the current field is terminated thereafter. All white space before the next non-white space character is skipped, so a null column would be skipped.

1. The reason for the skipping of the consecutive delimiters is the inclusion of the enclosure specifications “OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ‘”’

If the enclosure is optional that character need not match the enclosure char, but if it's mandatory that character must match or the row will be rejected.

2. Specify fields as part of fields clause and the ones which do not appear in columns clause.
3. You can also try changing delimiter from comma to something else.

Comment: Hi, I don't have the optionally enclosed by part in it. I tried with it but didn't work, but original working code didn't have that in it. Goes 

records delimited by newline 
               badfile SEPA_FILES:''mem_verify_'||v_insurer||'_incoming.bad''
               logfile SEPA_FILES:''mem_verify_'||v_insurer||'_incoming.log''
               skip 1
               fields terminated by 0X''09''
               LRTRIM
               missing field values are null 
               (

Comment: Try changing delimiter from comma to something else?

Comment: Or you can do this by specifying the fields in the file as part of the fields clause, and specifying the ones that don't appear with the column transforms clause. Answer edited

Comment: I tried changing delimiter to comma, but that didn't work. It's a tab delimited file anyway and was working previously. 

Also, other name is in the file and sometimes (rarely though) isn't blank so when that happens, it's actually fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work.

Changed LRTRIM to RTRIM and it seems to be working. Not sure why but that did it